# Is there any way allows my Android wear connect to MYSQL

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Just like what I mentioned from the question.
My watch is LG Urban, when I was developing my android app, I can use the mysql connector to connect with my DB server. Can I use the same to make my Android wear connect to mysql?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Android Wear 2, proxying data requests through the phone has been replaced by direct network access from the watch. So going forward, your existing code to connect to a MySQL server should work essentially unchanged on the watch.

More details here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/network-access.html

A couple of caveats:

- Wear 2 is only now rolling out to the majority of devices (your Urbane probably doesn't have it yet, for example).
- You should try to minimize the data being transferred to/from the watch; these devices have enough issues with battery life as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can talk to the DB via the phone. You can send messages back and forth and also sync data to the wearable.

You could therefore - indirectly - get whatever data you want from the DB and display it on the watch. You could also get sensor data from the watch and save it back to the DB.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your help!